# Input command to socket from one thread and continuous printing of socket data from another thread

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm trying to create simple pyqt5 application for Continuous reading and writing using sockets. My requirements are:

1. Window-1 : User can send the command to sockets
2. Window-2 : Continuous printing of socket data as mentioned below:

```
while True:
    recvmsg = UDPClientSocket.recvfrom(1024)        
    print(recvmsg[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
```

is a bad form to to things continuously because it freezes GUI.The reason of that you put endless loop to the main thread.

GUI and Operating System (User indirectly) communicating between main thread.

> [Good video explained what threads is](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hwTYDQ0zZOw)

Python has good threads module.You should build stream structrue in another thread and put listener on it.